# What is the significance of moment generating functions

Tags: moment-generating-functions

I can not see why moment generating functions are useful. What are the applications? I know they give an alternate representation of a probability functions and I guess they can be easier to work with in some cases, but are there any other applications?

Comment: to add to your list: establishing probability bounds here and there ...

Comment: Well, calculating expected values of powers of a variable (which indirectly helps in calculating variances). There's also Chernoff bounds. Oh, and given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $M_X = M_Y$, then $X = Y$.